# Issue Tracking List Template for Moss 2077

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can any one help me to download the Issue Tracking List Template for Moss 2007..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You do need to download it. It is available OOTB

http://referpages.com/wp/2007/12/issues/